# Why Geocoder Locale.US return address in Arabic in Dubai

Tags: android, arabic, google-geocoder

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);
```

The above code returns the address in English irrespective of device language. But in Dubai, the above code is not working and returns the address in Arabic.

How I get the address in English in Dubai using Geocoder?

Comment: Looks like it's [intended behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825571) from the Geocoder backend service

Comment: Try to use `Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, new Locale("en"));`

Comment: Try `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: We have tried Locale.US but no effect.

Comment: What do you mean by "in Dubai"? Do you mean that the request originates from Dubai, using a device in Arabic locale, geocoding a Dubai address? A combination?

Comment: Device is in Dubai but locale set to English

Answer (score 0):

What if you tricked the `Context` that you pass to the `GeoCoder`?

For example, by changing the context locale like in the following Kotlin code:

```kotlin
val configuration = Configuration(resources.configuration)
configuration.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
val newContext = createConfigurationContext(configuration)
val geocoder = Geocoder(newContext, Locale.getDefault())
```

I haven't tried it, just an idea that came to mind. My guess is the `GeoCoder` uses the passed `Context` to detect the preferred locale.